# Closed expression, in terms of n

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have been trying to derive an expression in terms of n for the following.  The closest I have been by the result is with log_2(n), (base 2).  Thank you :)

```
public static int v(int n) {
        int r = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i*=2) {
            r=r+1;  
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: You're off by 1, and need to truncate.  This is `floor(log2(n-1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this good enough for you:

```
public static int v2(int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return 0;
    return (int) (Math.log(n - 1) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
}
```

In other words `log_2(n-1)+1` for `n > 1` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me a little about your thought process for solving it?

Comment: @Dav1497 I'm not sure I can explain it really. An [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) happens often enough so that you learn to catch it. In this case it was clear that the answer should be something like `log_2(n)` because this what a pair of increment + multiply by 2 operations does. The `i<n` instead of `i<=n` is an obvious hint for `log_2(n-1)` and then you need to check some base case. `n=0` is obviously not the base case. `n=1` looks promising but the loop is not run yet and also `log(0)` is undefined. `n=2` gives the `+1` part. Check a few more to be sure.